# html helper doesn't look at the latest dll with Mvc 5 and Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

In my .cshtml page I have have upgraded my mvc 3 app o mvc 5 and upgraded kendo Ui to Q1 2014 release.

```
                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("Birthday"))
```

html always points to System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper.
I want that to use System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.

why it is not looking at the System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper ?

Comment: Is this actually a problem?  Maybe it's actually a feature.

Comment: because of that am getting runtime errors, saying it could find kendo

Comment: Please include all of the information that is relevant to your question, in the question.  Include the exact wording of any error messages you are getting.